How many white pawns to survive the black storm?
Given a $4\times 4$ chess board,

first white can put 7 white pawns on it;
then black will start a so called "black storm", that is to select 2
ranks (rows) and 2 files (columns), and wipe out all
pieces on them;

the request is to put 7 pawns nicely so that at
least 1 will survive the black storm.
This can be done, for example, white can put pawns on squares $a1$, $a2$, $b2$, $b4$, $c3$, $d1$ and $d4$.
However, 6 pawns are not enough to guarantee the survival. (Unfortunately my proof is not rigorous, for details, pls refer to Calvin's answer.)
Let's note this fact as $$f(4)=7$$
Now, if the chess board is $6\times 6$ chess board, suppose the black storm will wipe out $3$ files and $3$ ranks, how many white pawns are needed so that at least 1 will survive the black storm? i.e. what is $f(6)$?
If it's a standard the chess board, i.e. $8\times 8$, suppose the black storm will wipe out $4$ files and $4$ ranks, how many white pawns are needed so that at least 1 will survive the black storm? i.e. $f(8)=?$
More generally, for a $2n\times 2n$ chess board, suppose the black storm will wipe out $n$ files and $n$ ranks, is it possible to find $f(2n)$? i.e. $f(2n)$ white pawns are needed so that at least 1 will survive the black storm?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you tried and why it doesn't seem to push through.
Basically, all the hard work is done in the $f(4)$ case, so study it well and come up with simple proofs, which allow for an easy extension to the larger cases. EG Your proof of $f(4) > 6$ pawns is too complicated, so go back and rework it till you can see how to extend it to $f(6) > k$.

Show that $f(4) > 6$.

If there are 6 pawns, then there exists 2 rows with at least 4 pawns total on them.     (WHY?)
Clear those 2 rows, leaving at most 2 pawns. We can remove them with the other 2 columns.
If there are 5 or fewer pawns, throw in more pawns till there are 6, and follow the above.


Show that $f(4) \leq 7$

Thank you for providing a construction. Please think about how we can describe it, in a way that it could be extended to a larger board.
A slightly better representation, where the pattern is more obvious, is
$$ \begin{array}{l l l l}  x & x & & \\
 & x & x & \\
 x &  & x & \\ 
& & & x \\
\end{array}  $$
What is a written description of the pattern? (IE Without resorting to a graphical representation like $a1, a2, b2, b3, c3, c1, d4$)
Without resorting to "try all cases", how can we prove that 2 rows and 2 columns are not enough to remove all 7 pawns in this setup? Can the written description help?


Hence conclude that $f(4) = 7 $.
Show that $f(6) > 9$.

If there are 9 pawns, then there exists 3 rows with at least 6 pawns total on them. (WHY? )
Clear those 3 rows, leaving at most 3 pawns. We can remove them with the other 3 columns.
If there are 8 or fewer pawns ...


Show that $f(6) \leq 10$

Exploit the pattern above
Prove that 3 rows and 3 columns are not enough to remove all 10 pawns.


Hence conclude that $f(6) = 10$.
What are the versions for $f(8)$?
What are the versions for $f(2n)$?


 $f(2n) = 3n+1$


For technical details, pls refer to Calvin's answer. This is just a side note.
To show $f(2n)=3n+1$, first we notice $3n$ is not enough: to have black wiping out minimum pawns on $n$ rows, white has to place $n$ rows each with 2 pawns and $n$ rows each with 1, but this come to $2n$, then black can wipe out the rest $n$ pawns by $n$ columns.
To place $3n+1$ pawns to survive the "black storm", we shown an example of $n=4$:


on the top $n-1=3$ rows, $n-1$ queens are just holding positions temporarily for pawns, eliminating pawns on these squares, each row wiping out also clear one column

on the down $n+1=3$ rows, $2n+2$ pawns are placed so that wiping out $k$ rows will only wipe out $k-1$ columns


After replacing the queens with pawns, white will be ready:

after black wiping out $n=4$ rows, only $n-1=3$ columns will be cleared, $n+1=5$ columns are remained guarded;
after black further wiping out $n=4$ columns, at least one pawn will survive

, so, $3n+1=13$ works.

I know it's just a meaningless coincidence, but if $n$ is odd then the Collatz problem takes $2n$ to $3n+1$ (and then to $(3n+1)/2$), via $n$.

Great! For rigor, do you have a way to explain why "after black wiping out $n$ rows, only $n-1$ columns will  be cleared"?
